# In Karate framework how can automate IOS elements with index?

Tags: karate

I automated quite a few test with API and Android using karate and until now I am very successful. I recently started to automate IOS and I am stuck at one place, can anyone please help me with my question,

I have an IOS object with index in it , how can I automate same in Karate ?

[image]

Comment: are you getting any specific error while trying to performing this action?

Comment: Thanks Babu for asking, It worked after I use only index without name

Comment: @Babu Sekaran  thanks for coming back, I resolved it by adding just index *driver.click("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@index=1]") and since its been many day I raised this question I dont really remember exact error message (if  I remember it correctly it was giving wrong xPath error)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For above shared selectors. Both of the below statements worked for me in Karate for iOS:

- AND driver.click('Next')
- AND driver.click('//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Next"]')